# Include Amount In Blockchain Receiving API

Tags: blockchain

how do i inlcude btc needed to be sent to the generated receiving address
coz there only callback_url, key, xpub

https://blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=xPub&callback=callback_url&key=api_key

Comment: See also https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1226896 , which contains discussion of the API and how to use it.